# Missing Ubuntu in boot menu after installing Cent OS 6

Tags: ubuntu, centos, dual-boot, grub

I had Ubuntu in my hard disk and after installing CentOS 6 on it I am not able to see Ubuntu in the boot menu. My /bootgrub/grub.conf file looks as follows:
[image: pic]

What changes do I need to make in this file so that I am able to see Ubuntu in the boot menu? Are there other possible solutions to fix this issue? I would highly appreciate suggestions.

Comment: Please don't post text as images! Just copy the text directly into your question and use the [formatting tools](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/formatting) to make it look clear.

Comment: Are you certain that Ubuntu still exists on your drives? On what disk and partition? Go check that out and be sure.   It is possible of course you have instructed the Centos Installer (knowingly or unknowingly) to wipe out your Ubuntu distribution's partitions. If you did, they are gone.

Comment: Yes I am certain that Ubuntu still exists. I am just not sure how to make it appear in the boot menu :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

CentOS 6 doesn't include other Linux OS in the boot menu.

Solution : Run an Ubuntu live-DVD (or a live Ubuntu from USB), and do : 1) `sudo update-grub` .... and 2) `sudo grub-install /dev/sdb/` ( If you want to boot from sdb/.)

---

Comment: Why in thew world would the OP need to boot into a live session? All they need is to run `sudo update-grub` from CentOS. And why would they install it on `/dev/sdb`?

Comment: @terdon: Because CentOS6 doesn't have an 'update-grub', nor does it use GRUB2.  You'd need to tell CentOS to install the bootloader to its /boot partition instead of the MBR, and have Ubuntu's grub chainload to it (or vice-versa).  Or set up an ubuntu grub2 config with the CentOS kernels, although you'd have to update it for every kernel update it CentOS.